# BorderLayout Design Error

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, border-layout

I have some code like the below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new BorderTest();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JButton("West"), "West");
    p.add(new JButton("East"), "East");
    p.add(new JButton("North"), "North");
    p.add(new JButton("Center"), "Center");
    p.add(new JButton("South"), "South");

    Container c = f.getContentPane();
    c.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How would I modify my code to make it so the buttons North and South are the same width as Center and West and East expand vertically to fill the space?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the "north", "south" and "center" into another container, using a `BorderLayout`, add this container to the "center" position of `p`

Answer (score 5):

Add the "North", "South" and "Center" components to another container, using a `BorderLayout`, add this container to the `CENTER` position of the main container

[image: Layout]

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel middle = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    middle.add(new JButton("NORTH"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    middle.add(new JButton("CENTER"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    middle.add(new JButton("SOUTH"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    p.add(middle);
    p.add(new JButton("EAST"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    p.add(new JButton("WEST"), BorderLayout.WEST);
```